# Xpath. Unable to select text of label - when another element like <input> is between the <label> tags

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, cucumber

Java dev and new to Xpath. Googled and RTFM-ed quite a bit but stuck. Company has a large webapplication written in Java, using the Java Wicket framework.  Using Selenium in combination with Cucumber and Junit for testing. Hence Lots of Xpath expressions are needed to be written. **Stuck with the following.**

A screen with a form and two toggles () and text behind it . Relevant snippet.

```
    <label>
    <input id="idf1" name="removeConditionViaTreeStep:resultsRadioGroup" value="radio3" checked="checked" type="radio"> 
    Safe to delete
    </label>

    <label>
    <input id="idf2" name="removeConditionViaTreeStep:resultsRadioGroup" value="radio4" type="radio">
    Unsafe to delete
    </label>
```

Note: Using the Wicket framework means that the attributes id and value are/can be different each time the application runs so can NOT use them. Can NOT change the html either.

**Plan A** 
I wanted to select a specific toggle (and emulate clicking/selecting it) by using the label text as a uniq selector but the fact that between the   tags there are .. gives me problems. In clean label situations I can select a certain label without problems.
Can't get things like //label[contains(text(),'Unsafe to delete')] to work in this case.

**Gave up and went for plan B.**

Using firepath addon for firebug for testing and came up with the following: //input[@name='removeConditionViaTreeStep:resultsRadioGroup']
This results in firepath in two matches. I hoped to use something like [2] to select the second toggle, but could not figure it out.

**Plan C - resorting to Java and Xpath worked.**
List elements = findElementsByXpath("//input[@name='removeConditionViaTreeStep:resultsRadioGroup']");
elements.get(1) // select second toggle.

Have this feeling "//label[contains(text(),'Unsafe to delete')]"  does not work because everything is streamed and nothing is held in memory by the Webdriver of selenium. Hence the  element breaks the  stream or something like that......

Perhaps someone can give a few hints and pointers or even a solution for plan A and B.

Edit corrected the closing parenthesis typo as mentioned by Bill Hileman.

Comment: Try `"//label[normalize-space()='Unsafe to delete']"`

Comment: have you tried something like `elements.getAtrribute("textContent");`

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you can not change the HTML, but maybe you can run the application in wickets development mode on the test environment? This way, if I remember correctly, `wicket:id` should be rendered and you would have an easier time to select elements.

Comment: The tests need to run against a wicket application in production mode. Development mode introduces some extra stuff on the rendered page which selenium doesn't like. Otherwise I could even do some stuff like mentioned in https://www.jdev.it/testing-a-wicket-application-with-selenium-ide/. But the team has decided against that a few years back as the html would be polluted quite a bit and as we have complex pages if something would be added the it would break the tests to easily. Thats what the devs tell me. Thanks for the comments btw.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath attempt as you typed it is:

```
//label[contains(text(),'Unsafe to delete']
```

Unless that was a typo here only, you missed a closing parenthesis.

```
//label[contains(text(),'Unsafe to delete')]
```

That xpath should work.

Comment: Even with a closing parenthesis your `XPath` won't work

Comment: Do you mean that it won't return the label webelement or that it won't be clickable?  If the latter, just adding /input to the end would get the input element, or am I wrong again? '//label[contains(text(),'Unsafe to delete')]/input'

Comment: I mean it won't return a `label`. If you check `count(//label/text())` you'll see that it return `2`. It means that `label` element has 2 text nodes: the first one consists of just space characters- it doesn't contain any `"Unsafe to delete"`. The one that should work is `//label[contains(text()[2],'Unsafe to delete')]`. Note, that you search for `"Unsafe to delete"` in second text node which really contains required string

Comment: Nice... I didn't catch that.

Comment: Hi Guys. Currently at home enjoying the evening so can't check. From the top of my head. Firepath doesn't find a match when looking for "Unsafe to delete". The cucumber test borks because it can't find what it is looking for.

@Anderson. Are the space characters being caused by the fact that [1] is what is between <label> and <input> (as in nothing or whitespace)? 
If so then it makes sense. 

Wrt to plan B and trying to follow your reasoning does this mean that with
        //input[2]@name='removeConditionViaTreeStep:resultsRadioGroup']
I could select toggle 2??

Comment: @user1987876, `text()` is first text node (`text()[1]`, the one between `<label>` and `<input>`) which contains spaces/new line character only. You can use index to select second `input` element as `"(//input[@name='removeConditionViaTreeStep:resultsRadioGroup'])[2]"`

Comment: @Anderson. Thank you and the others who have helped. The normalize-space() and the [2] both work. I've now a bit more understanding how Xpath works so thanks for that.